# could not load cudart64_110.dll tensorflow error

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, nvidia

I am trying to set up tensorflow with gpu support. I have these installed at the moment.

python v3.9.10

tensorflow v2.7.0

cuda toolkit v11.2

cudnn v8.1

visual studio 2019

I have tried reinstalling all of these components multiple times but I still get the error "could not load dynamic library 'curadt64_110.dll'" when running the python file. cudart64_110.dll is there in the cuda toolkit installation directory in the bin folder. All relevant folders have been added to path. Further I have tried with cuda toolkit v11.6 and cudnn v8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem over the last few days and have just managed to get it to work.

My solution was reinstalling python. I know you have stated you've reinstalled python multiple times, but in what capacity? I've seen on another answer (unfortunately I cannot find the link to it) that if the python version is installed from the windows store, it is unable to access certain DLL files.

The version I installed is from

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3910/

and is the very last download file (x64). Select the automatic download option (and ensure it is automatically added to PATH). Then you need to reinstall tensorflow.

Open your cmd terminal and go to the directory that the new python install is in (if unsure where this is, you can find it in your PATH definition as it's there now) using the command

> cd 'NEW_PYTHON_LOACTION' (copy the location here)

Then run your pip command

> pip install tensorflow

This should install the latest version of tensorflow (2.7.0). This is obviously in addition to wherever it is already on your machine, but you can clean up later if you want.

You should already have CUDA and cuDNN as per every guide ever with versions 11.2 and 8.1 respectively and these should be added to path as well. If unsure check this guide out https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/IubEtS2JAiY

And that should do it. Just open python as you would normally (ensure it is the new version) and import tensorflow. Then run the line:

> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

and you should see the output:

> Num GPUs Available:  1

Do note that you will need to install all the other libraries as well for this new version of python.

Good luck